# linq count error: DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. Parameter name: input

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to run the following linq query:

```
var entries = from entry in _db.Entries
    select new CommentSummary()
    {
         NumberOfComments = entry.Message.Count(),
         UserName = entry.Name
    };
```

when I execute the query, it throws the mentioned error:
Message=DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.
Parameter name: input

If I use

```
var entries = from entry in _db.Entries
    group entry by entry.Name into groupedByName
    orderby groupedByName.Count() descending
    select new CommentSummary
    {
         NumberOfComments = groupedByName.Count(),
         UserName = groupedByName.Key
    };
```

there is no error, but the Comments are not counted correctly: all NumberOfComments values are "1", and there should be some "1" and some "0".
Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should use 'by new' after 'group'. I hope this will help you.

```
var entries = from entry in _db.Entries
    group entry by new { entry.Name } into groupedByName
    select new
    {
         groupedByName.Key.Name,
         NumberOfComments = groupedByName.Count(x => x.Name != null)
    };
```